# Publishing an Android app with Advertisements

Tags: android, admob, ads, android-pay

I am having an Android app with advertisements (admob). There is nothing to purchase. Up to now, I have been reading and following the instructions given by *Android For Programmers* book, even for the registration and creating of my android market account.

Now, I have an issue. when I am about to publish the app, it is asking whether the application is free or paid.

I have created my account in `admob` as well. So, when it comes to apps with `advertisements`, what does it become? I guess it is free, but since I earn money from ads, do I need to publish this as a "paid" app?

This is my first android market publish, so I need your help.

Comment: It is a free app. if you are not charging any amount for downloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paid means in this case, that user will have to purchases your app. It has nothing to do with ads.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not charging anything from user to download and install app then you should publish it as FREE app, doesn't matter whether you have integrated AdMob or any advertisements to generate revenue.